# how to get data from table and insert it into another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

checkorder.php

```
<?php include("koneksi.php");mysql_select_db("project2");
$code = $_POST['code'];
$name = $sql = "Select name from 'orders' where 'code' = '<?php $_POST['code'] ?>' ";
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$nameorder = $_POST['nameorder'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];  
$address= $_POST['address'];    
$price  = $sql= "Select price from 'orders' where 'code' = '<?php $_POST['code'] ?>' ";
$totalprice = $price * $_POST['amount'];
    $sql = " INSERT INTO orders (idorder, date, nameorder, email, code, name, amount, price, total price)
    VALUES 
    (default, NOW(), '$code', 'name','$amount','$nameorder','$email','$address')";
    mysql_query($sql) ; ?>
```

I want to insert data using php. 
code,name,price get from table product, is it possible using this way?
Because when I try to input data it always show error in $name.

Comment: Why not just use a INSERT INTO...SELECT? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Use query select at first then fetch what u want out

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
$query = "Select * from `orders` where `code` = '$code' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$name = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)['name']; //get the name
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$nameorder = $_POST['nameorder'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];  
$address= $_POST['address'];.....................
```

Comment: It's still showing error $name when i try to input data, error message "Parse error: parse error in C:\xampp\htdocs\project2\checkorder.php on line 7", line 7 `$name = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)['name'];`

Comment: I just browse and get this way `$query = "Select name from product where 'code' = '$code' ";$result = mysql_query($query); $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`. Now it's not showing error, but data doesn't get in to the table?

Comment: Select name from product where `code` = '$code'.
copy line above. use ` (button under esc) to mark column or table instead of ' (next to enter btn).

Comment: Or else dont use if u dont get it

Comment: Im sorry, what is difference between ' and `?

Comment: ` to let mysql know it's a column or table. ' is value